# Why is custom message not working in grails when tried with the following?

Tags: validation, grails

i am a beginner in grails and i have the following problem. Please help.

package racetrack

class Users {

```
String userName
String password

static constraints = {
    userName(nullable:false, maxSize:20)
    password(password:true, minSize: 8,
            validator: {

                return (it.matches("(.*[\\d])"))?true: ['noNumber']
                return (it.matches("(.*[\\W])"))?true: ['noSpecialCh']
                return (it.matches("(.*[a-z])"))?true: ['noLower']
                return (it.matches("(.*[A-Z])"))?true: ['noUpper']
            }
    )
}
```

}

I created the above domain and in message.properties, i added the following:
users.password.validator.noNumber=should contain at least one number
users.password.validator.noLower=should contain at least one lower case letter as well
users.password.validator.noUpper=should contain number as well
users.password.validator.noSpecialCh=should contain number as well

however, i am not given required messages when tried with faulty values. Suppose, if i give no number in the password "should contain at least one number" message was expected but i only get does not match custom validation message.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is that Groovy, unlike Java, allows multiple `return` statements. If you converted that to Java it wouldn't compile.

Groovy allows multiple `return` statements, but obviously only considers the first, so with your code you have one check, not four, essentially

```
(it.matches("(.*[\\d])")) ? true : ['noNumber']
```

It should be something like this:

```
if (!it.matches("(.*[\\d])")) {
   return ['noNumber']
}

if (!it.matches("(.*[\\W])")) {
   return ['noSpecialCh']
}

if (!it.matches("(.*[a-z])")) {
   return ['noLower']
}

if (!it.matches("(.*[A-Z])")) {
   return ['noUpper']
}
```

except that all of the regexes are broken, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: It is not still working. in messages.properties, i get "unused property" hover message when hovered on users.password.validator.noNumber
users.password.validator.noLower
users.password.validator.noUpper and users.password.validator.noSpecialCh

Comment: Did you fix those regexes? They don't do what you think they do.

Comment: Nope, i have not fixed them. "They dont do what you think they do" can you please tell me what they do?

Comment: One question per question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165775/issue-in-giving-custom-error-message-when-using-custom-validation-in-grails

Comment: Burt's answer helped me solve a similar problem. I was either returning a String or a boolean. Multiple return statements work with boolean only, using return value true or false.