# Issue in giving custom error message when using custom validation in grails

Tags: regex, validation, grails

I have the following issue:

**User.groovy**

class Users {

```
String userName
String passwd

static constraints = {
    userName(nullable:false, maxSize:20)
    passwd(password:true,
            validator: {val, obj, errors->

                if (!(obj.passwd.matches("(.*[\\d])"))) errors.rejectValue('passwd', 'noNumber')

                if (!obj.passwd.matches("(.*[\\W])")) errors.rejectValue('passwd', 'noSpecialCh')

                if (!obj.passwd.matches("(.*[a-z])")) errors.rejectValue('passwd', 'noLower')

                if (!obj.passwd.matches("(.*[A-Z])")) errors.rejectValue('passwd', 'noUpper')

            }
    )
}
```

}

**messages.properties**

noNumber.racetrack.Users.passwd=password should contain at least one number
noSpecialCh.racetrack.Users.passwd=password should contain at least one special character
noLower.racetrack.Users.passwd=password should contain at least one lower case letter
noUpper.racetrack.Users.passwd=password should contain at least one upper case letter

These lines of code give me error messages.

However,

when i enter "1222s" in password it gives the error messages:
password should contain at least one number
password should contain at least one special character
password should contain at least one upper case letter

even though i have entered number.

when i enter "sss1" in password it gives the error messages:
password should contain at least one lower case letter
password should contain at least one special character
password should contain at least one upper case letter

even though i have entered some lower cases.

It seems as if it checks the last character in the end and gives error messages.

What am i doing wrong in User.groovy or messages.properties? Are my Regular expressions wrong?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes are wrong. It should be `\d+` for number, `\W+` for special character, `[a-z]+` and so on. Special symbols are escaped with one slash. `+` means - one or more occurrences of pattern. No need for `.*` and grouping with `()`.

Comment: doing that did not help :(